# Diffeomorphism imply nonzero Jacobian?

Tags: calculus, differential-geometry, jacobian

Why if $\varphi:U\subseteq\mathbb{R}^N\to V\subseteq\mathbb{R}^N$ is bijective and $\varphi, \varphi^{-1}$ are of class $C^1$ then the jacobian:

$\det(D\varphi (x))\neq 0,\ \forall\ x\in U$???

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $x\in U \subseteq \mathbb R^n$

$$\varphi^{-1}(\varphi(x))=x=id(x)$$

Take the Jacobian on both sides* and apply the chain rule on the left-hand side**:

$$D\varphi^{-1}(\varphi(x))\cdot D\varphi(x) = I_n$$

So $D\varphi(x)$ is invertible $\forall x \in U$.

*Can do this since functions are differentiable.
**Can do this since they are $C^1$.

Answer (score 9):

Because both $\varphi$ and $\varphi^{-1}$ are $C^1$ you can apply the chain rule and you get $$D\varphi^{-1}(\varphi(x))\circ D\varphi(x)=D(\varphi^{-1}\circ \varphi)(x)=D(id_U)(x)=Id.$$
Hence $$\det(D\varphi^{-1}(\varphi(x)))\det\left ( D\varphi(x)\right)=\det(Id)=1$$ so $\det\left ( D\varphi(x)\right)\neq 0$.

Comment: it might be good to emphasize that we can apply the chain rule precisely because both $\varphi$ and $\varphi^{-1}$ are already known to be differentiable